# How to create an online repository on a Linux hosting using tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, online-repository

I want to setup an online repository on my Linux hosting account I have. I want to a combination of `Tortoise SVN` and `Ankh SVN` for this, this will be an ASP.NET MVC 4 project for which I will be using Visual Studio 2010.

Firstly, is it even possible to do this ? i.e to setup an online repostiory on a Linux hosting account, I know this question may sound very naive, but I am new to this code hosting.

Also I stricty want to use only `Tortoise SVN` and `Ankh SVN` for this. And I dont want to use `Git` or `Hg` for this.

Please advise me on the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

No way. Period

### Longer answer

You **must** to use SVN-server administration tools for creating repository (and building RA-access levels), not client-level tools

### Long answer

You have to have:

- SVN (installed) on server side
- Configured and running at least one type of SVN-server on Linux host
- Created (by svn admin tools) repository with configured ACL

None of the above tasks can be executed with TSVN

### Final Note

SVN Book is your best friend, at least chapters [Repository Administration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.html) and [Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html)